processing bad actor submissions
Processing through logs, the following is noticed, the submission of a param as such:
"user[comment]" which happens to be a variant extracted from their reading of the page's HTML.  Normally, one would process in rails the parameters with symbols params[:user][:comment].  Mixing symbols into the modified submisison string is convoluted.
How should one intercept this submission?

Unless you want to start playing in the middleware -- just let strong parameters do its job and ignore anything that is not legitimate.

The thing is, by letting strong params do its thing, one ends up conveying some information to bad actors. The goal is to quietly redirect to home page (the least one can 'divulge')

If they can see your form -- what exactly are you hiding?

the response, can say something. By redirecting to the home, it says little more than what was already said.

I am assuming want the middleware to reject something because of a general iffiness of the supplied parameters before it even hits the controller.  That means either monkey patching Rack or writing your own middleware -- both endeavors likely to make your app less secure without significant effort.  Suggest checking out firewall options offered by your host for filtering suspect requests as a more fruitful investment.

you don't have to start from scratch with middleware https://github.com/rack/rack-attack

You shouldn't be intercepting it.
This whole idea hinges on a fundamental misconception that the params use symbols as keys which is just not true. Your proposed filter would actually do more harm than good as you would be blocking almost every legit POST/PATCH request to your application.
HTTP parameters are just key value pairs which are parsed by the Rack middleware. The keys in the resulting hash are strings. After all the params parser should not assume that the parameters are safe to symbolize.
irb(main):006> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("foo[bar]=baz")
=> {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"baz"}}
irb(main):007> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("foo[:bar]=baz")
=> {"foo"=>{":bar"=>"baz"}}      

Rails wraps the parsed parameters from Rack in ActionController::Parameters which is a hash like object but with indifferent access so that you can access the values with a symbol.
Requests that are suspected to be malicous on other more credible grounds can be intercepted with Rack attack on the middleware layer or even up top at the web server level (Apache, NGiNX etc). But beware of falling into the trappings of security by obscurity.

Very helpful explanation of the mechanics and thus how Rack attack can be approached.  And yes, this is not intended as a sole mechanism (strong params remain in place), just an independent layer (and yes, it has its motivations which do not warrant publicity)
